# Running React@0.13.0 and react@0.14.0-beta3 together

Tags: reactjs

A part of my project runs react@0.14.0-beta3 and at the same time ReactART which is also used in the same app uses react@0.13.0. When I run the app, I get the error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined at Object.ReactMount.findComponentRoot
```

Is it possible to run both the versions, so ReactART will load react@0.14.0-beta3 in it's namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because of [running two copies of React on a page can give errors because both use ID '.0'](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1939).

Alternatively, you can [wait for `react-art` to be updated](https://github.com/reactjs/react-art/issues/56).